# HYperledger composer v0.19.2 network start fails with Error [lscc] executeDeployOrUpgrade -> ERRO 46e cannot get package for chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

hscsys@ggnlabvm-decent01:~/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11$ composer network install -c PeerAdmin7@hsc-network -a hscdb2@0.0.1.bna
✔ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Successfully installed business network hscdb2, version 0.0.1

hscsys@ggnlabvm-decent01:~/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11$ composer network start --networkName hsc-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 -A admin -S adminpw -c PeerAdmin7@hsc-network
Starting business network hsc-network at version 0.0.1

Processing these Network Admins:
        userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: cannot get package for chaincode (hsc-network:0.0.1))
Command failed

**Docker Peer logs :**
**

> 2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [lscc] executeDeployOrUpgrade -> ERRO 46e
>   cannot get package for chaincode (hsc-network:0.0.1)-err:open
>   /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/hsc-network.0.0.1: no such file
>   or directory

**
2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [shim] func1 -> DEBU 46f [35f3cb07]Transaction completed. Sending COMPLETED
2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [shim] func1 -> DEBU 470 [35f3cb07]Move state message COMPLETED
2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [shim] handleMessage -> DEBU 471 [35f3cb07]Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED(state:ready)
2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [shim] func1 -> DEBU 472 [35f3cb07]send state message COMPLETED
2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [chaincode] processStream -> DEBU 473 [35f3cb07]Received message COMPLETED from shim
2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 474 [35f3cb07]Fabric side Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED in state ready
2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 475 [35f3cb076594d00463deec6952700cd3f69ea7b345676360d5d0f1511d12e31d]HandleMessage- COMPLETED. Notify
2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [chaincode] notify -> DEBU 476 notifying Txid:35f3cb076594d00463deec6952700cd3f69ea7b345676360d5d0f1511d12e31d, channelID:composerchannel
2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 477 Exit
2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> DEBU 478 [composerchannel][35f3cb07] Exit
2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] GetTxSimulationResults -> DEBU 479 Simulation completed, getting simulation results
2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] Done -> DEBU 47a Done with transaction simulation / query execution [35f3cb076594d00463deec6952700cd3f69ea7b345676360d5d0f1511d12e31d]
2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> DEBU 47b [composerchannel][35f3cb07] Exit
**

> 2018-05-14 03:14:31.481 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> ERRO 47c
>   [composerchannel][35f3cb07] simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode
>   name:"lscc"  response status 500 for txid:

** 35f3cb076594d00463deec6952700cd3f69ea7b345676360d5d0f1511d12e31d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a network you need to specify the correct name and version of the network. If you look at the output from your install command

> hscsys@ggnlabvm-decent01:~/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11$ composer network install -c PeerAdmin7@hsc-network -a hscdb2@0.0.1.bna
>
> ✔ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
>
> Successfully installed business network hscdb2, version 0.0.1

The last line shows you the name and version of the business network that was just installed (**hscdb2**, **0.0.1**). Therefore the start command would be

> hscsys@ggnlabvm-decent01:~/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11$ composer network start --networkName hscdb2 --networkVersion 0.0.1 -A admin -S adminpw -c PeerAdmin7@hsc-network

This is the name and version you specified in your package.json of your business network.